# Special character issues reading csv. ASCII with UTF-8 fgetcsv not working. Better Solution?

Tags: php, mongodb, csv, utf-8

I'm reading in a csv which has both ascii and UTF-8 characters and putting in into an associative array to be stored in mongo. I looked everywhere for an answer and finally came up with one. fgetcsv has issues with special characters as has been noted many times in many other posts.

For example:

Note:
Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function.

None of the other solutions were working for me. I decided to go with str_getcsv instead. I wanted to post this in the hopes that this would hopefully help someone else out. Also to see if anyone else had a better solution.

Credit does need to be given to Mr.Williams and durik. Posts are here. This link was the best I found on the issue. http://www.kinghost.com.br/php/function.str-getcsv.php

```
$csvheader = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($argv[1], "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($row = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE) {

    if (!$csvHeader) {

        //format csv header row into array of strings
        $row = str_replace('"', '', $row);
        $row = str_replace("\r\n", '', $row);

        $num = strlen($row) - strlen(str_replace(",", "", $row));

        $csvHeader = array();
        $csvHeader = explode( ",", $row , ($num+1) );

    } else {

         //line that fixed my issue
         $row = utf8_encode($row);

         $Data = str_getcsv($row, "\n"); 
         foreach($Data as &$row){
             $row = str_getcsv($row, ",");
             $data[] = array_combine($csvHeader, $row);
         } 
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

example result: The value field was causing the issues.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52932826436b1cde170041d6"),
"id" : "48",
"afdrthdrth" : "11259",
"drthdrth" : "3439428",
"fdrth" : "87",
"firht" : "COPYRIGHT",
"value" : "©2005 Junghvghme / Mugcfgnss, allcfgncfgserved",
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's good that you've managed to find your own solution. The best way to do this on SO is to ask the question and then answer it in a separate answer. This way people can add better solutions later. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. I'll also have a think about your question :)

Comment: Sorry, first time. That was the one thing I missed when reading the docs on how to post a question like this. It was 3 something am =-)